# Pgfplots: how do I fill an area over a curve?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm working with pgfplots, and I have a curve on a graph which is basically a rect. I would like to color the part on top of it, not the part under it. I have this code:

```
\addplot[fill=\sixthplotcolor, fill opacity=0.5, thick, mark=none, color=\sixthplotcolor]
coordinates {
    (1, 40)
    (10, 400)
    (100, 4000)
    (150, 6000)
    (200, 8000)
    (250, 10000)
    (300, 12000)
    (350, 14000)
    (500, 20000)
    (750, 30000)
    (1000, 40000)
} \closedcycle;
```

Which colors under the curve, but not over.

Can anyone help me? Sorry for the dumb question, I'm new to pgfplots.

Comment: For this specific example finish of your plot command with `-- (axis cs:0,40000) \closedcycle;` and it should fill the upper part.

Comment: @percusse: Or just `-| (current plot begin);`.

Comment: @Jake Ah, sure. Much better.

Comment: Well, thanks! What does `-- (axis cs:0,40000)` and `-| (current plot begin);` do exactly?

Comment: @Madhatter: `-| (current plot begin)` draws a line from the current position (which is the end of the plot, if you add the code at the end of the `\addplot` command) to the start of the plot (`current plot begin`), using a line that runs horizontally first and then vertically. This approach only works as expected if your last point on the plot is also the maximum. Do you need this for more complicated plots as well? To what y-coordinate do you want to fill the area? The maximum value of the plot, or some specified value?

Comment: @Madhatter And the other one means *"understand the coordinate using the axis coordinate system"*.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Good first question. For future reference, please keep in mind that while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 7):

Version 1.10 of pgfplots has been released just recently, and it comes with a new solution for the problem to fill the area between plots.

For your simple case, the answer of percusse is the way to go.

However, for anything which is slightly more complex, the following approach might be good to know: it allows to fill the area between any two plots by means of the `fillbetween` library. In order to keep the knowledge base of this site up-to-date, I present a solution based on the new `fillbetween` library here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[name path=f, fill=red, fill opacity=0.5, thick, mark=none]
coordinates {
    (1, 40)
    (10, 400)
    (100, 4000)
    (150, 6000)
    (200, 8000)
    (250, 10000)
    (300, 12000)
    (350, 14000)
    (500, 20000)
    (750, 30000)
    (1000, 40000)
};

    \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,40000) -- (axis cs:1000,40000);

    \addplot[gray!50] fill between[of=f and axis];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This solution relies on `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}`: it assigns `name path=f` to the function of interest. Then, it generates an artificial `\path` which is neither drawn nor filled: this path is at `y=40000`. Finally, it fills the area between `f and axis` by means of `\addplot fill between`.

Answer (score 5):

As given in the comments, for this specific example using a predefined special coordinate and orthogonal lines can be used to achieve the goal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[fill=red, fill opacity=0.5, thick, mark=none]
coordinates {
    (1, 40)
    (10, 400)
    (100, 4000)
    (150, 6000)
    (200, 8000)
    (250, 10000)
    (300, 12000)
    (350, 14000)
    (500, 20000)
    (750, 30000)
    (1000, 40000)
} -| (current plot begin);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and if I don't want the limit in the middle, for example, in "2" position, how can I do with the same code?  `-| (current plot begin)`

Comment: @xiuhays see the other answer, this is too old.